# Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 8: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: odbc, out-of-memory, stack-size, sage-erp

I've been having trouble with this error for a few day now.

```
SQL Exception: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  8: Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Sage Line 50 v20, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\S20DBC32.dll).
```

After searching the net I found that I had to create a DWORD in my registry IRPStackSize if it was not created, so I did and gave it a value data of 50-Decimal or 32-Hexadecimal but the error still occurs.

Sage is a accounting software that we use and I access it with ODBC and withdraw data.

But I think that more problems occur from not enough storage space. As many of my systems don't connect to external databases or the connection timeouts.

So my question is:

1. The max I can set the data value of `IRPStackSize` is 50. Is this true or can I give it a bigger value.
2. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: In Microsoft's website it says that it maybe a problem NullSessionPipes registry.

Comment: How do you launch your program?